# Why doesn't this code put the row in the csv file into the table in sql?

Tags: python, csv, sqlite

For a school assignment we need to build a database in SQL with info about several artists. In the first part of the assignment we need to dump data from a CSV file into a SQL TABLE. But this does not seem to work in my code. The TABLES are there and the code runs without an error, but the data does not seem to be put in the TABLE. I do not know for what reason.

```
import sqlite3
import csv

artistsDb = sqlite3.connect("artists.sqlite3")

artistsDbCursor = artistsDb.cursor()
myQueryString = "CREATE TABLE artists (" +\
            "artistName CHAR (256)," +\
            "artistName CHAR (256)," +\
            "artistsDateOfBirth CHAR(256),"+\
            "artistYearsActive CHAR (256),"+\
            "artistsURL CHAR (256),"+\
            "artistsXNLFileName CHAR(256));"
artistsDbCursor.execute (  myQueryString )
artistsDb.commit

myFile = open ("artists.csv")
myReader = csv.reader ( myFile, delimiter = ";" )

myQueryString = "INSERT INTO artists VALUES ( ?, NULL, NULL,NULL,NULL)"
for myRowIterator in myReader: 
            myValues = myRowIterator
            artistsDbCursor.execute( myQueryString, myValues, )
```

Comment: `artistsDb.commit` needs to be called (although for DDL statements - it's immediate) - so it's `artistsDb.commit()` (not the parantheses), and after your for-loop to insert the rows, make sure you commit again to make sure the transaction takes place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jon Clement already mentions, you need to explicitely commit transactions using `artistsDb.commit()` (notice the parens - they are required for the function to be called) after your `for` loop.

There are also quite a few possible improvements to your script:

1. using context managers for files and database connections (to make sure they are properly closed)
2. using multiline (triple-quoted) strings instead of concatenation (for readability)
3. avoiding useless intermediary variables
4. use meaningfull names
5. open csv files in binary mode (this is required by the csv module for correct operations)

Here's an example rewrite with most points corrected:

```
# XXX you had artistName defined twice, which shouldn't work...
# I assume it was a copy-paste error and fixed it
# Also you may want to add a unique key to your table, use VARCHAR
# instead of CHAR, avoid 256 chars long fields when you don't need 
# that much, and use a date or datetime field for (resp.) dates and 
# datetime values.

create_table_sql = """
CREATE TABLE artists (
    artistName CHAR (256),
    artistsDateOfBirth CHAR(256),
    artistYearsActive CHAR (256),
    artistsURL CHAR (256),
    artistsXNLFileName CHAR(256)
    );
"""

# You insert NULL values but have not declared the matching fields
# as nullable. sqlite3 might accept this (sqlite3 accepts almost 
# anything) but any real SQL database will raise an error.
insert_artist_sql = "INSERT INTO artists VALUES (?, NULL, NULL,NULL,NULL)"

with sqlite3.connect("artists.sqlite3") as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(create_table_sql)
    db.commit() # this one is possibly useless but well

    with open("artists.csv", "rb") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ";")
        for row in reader: 
            # 'row' IS the value already
            cursor.execute(insert_artist_sql, row)

        # and this was the missing part...
        db.commit()
```